Controlling a device in a car using a button and ignition
I need to connect a device to my car. I thought about using an XOR gate because:
A - button
B - car ignition.
If the car's ignition is off (0), pressing the button (1) will turn on the device (1).
If the car's ignition is on (1), not pressing the button (0) will turn on the device (1).
However, I have two problems:
1 - When the button is pressed (1) and the car's ignition is on (1), the device will turn off (0).
2- When the ignition is on (1) and I press the button (1), the device should be turned off (0).
I think the most practical way to approach this case is to treat the device like a car radio.

What is the problem? What do you mean "not pressing the button will turn on the device"? What behavior do you want when the button is pressed and the ignition is turned on?

That's not the problem, I was describing how XOR functions on my setup. When the button is pressed and after I start the ignition I want it continuous running. At the same time I want the device to switch off if the button is clicked (again). The best illustration is to consider how an automobile radio operates and how to turn it on and off

then use an OR function

If the car's ignition is on (1), not pressing the button (0) will turn on the device (1) ... this makes no sense ... don't you want If the car's ignition is on (1), the device will be on(1). ?

Once again, approaching the device as though it were a car radio is the best way to address this challenge. The OR gate makes too sense, in that scenario.
So using OR:
if A = 1 and B = 1, the result is 1.
But I would like the following behavior:
A = 1 and B = 1
If I press the button again, making A = 0 and B = 1, the result should be 0. This scenario corresponds to an XOR, however an XOR is unable to verify its previous condition "if A = 1 and B = 1, the result is 1".

Pressing the button again - that still makes the button input a high, doesn't it? That's what the button does. Not pressing it is one state, pressing it is gives another state.

@jminhal You talk about XOR verifying previous condition, pushing the button again etc. Please modify your question with these details. To store the previous condition (or state) you need a memory element like a D flip flop. Combinational logic is not enough.
